# Animated movie with hybridized talking animals escaping from an island

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for animated movie (drawn) about an island where animals are crossing with another. I mean hybrids of lion and goat etc.

Main antagonist, as I remember, was a penguin who escaped from zoo because he hated kids throwing (stuff) on him/to him (probably trash). Main hero of the movie (boy or man, I don't really remember), with his friend, a white horse, are trying to free animals from cages on that island.

Movie ended with a scene on a ship with all escaping animals from the island.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should review the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking good identification questions to see if there are any additional details you can [edit] into your question.  For example, when did you see it?

Comment: @Boolean How is talking, thinking animals *not* fantasy?

Comment: @Zeiss - [Meta consensus is that talking animals alone isn't enough](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy?r=SearchResults)

Comment: In what year was this? Did the animation looked that age or older?  In what language was it?

Comment: @ibid and yet Roadrunner, Donald Duck, and such are treated as on topic.

Comment: That was early 2000's something around 2007-2009. Animation was drawed, as i good remember it looked like typical cartoon from this years. I watched it in Polish language, but for sure it's not Polish movie.

Comment: @ZeissIkon - see [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11528/are-the-donald-duck-comics-on-topic).

Comment: Hybridization of a lion with a goat goes well beyond the "talking animal" fantasy, so this question is indeed on-topic.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds vaguely like *Madagascar* -- a ship full of zoo animals runs aground and the animals escape into the (grossly unfamiliar) wilds of Madagascar.  Key line was "Nature!  Get it off, get it off!"

The movie follows their antics as they try to survive.  A very popular spinoff was the animated series "Penguins of Madagascar", based around a zoo habitat full of penguins running various *Hogan's Heroes* type operations.

Comment: Nah bro, madagascar was too obvious. That was animated movie that i had on VHS when i was young and i've never see it again. Nothing, even a picture on internet

Answer (score 4):

This is a huge coincidence. I thought about this movie today and it felt like a fever dream from when i was young lol. Found your question, hoping someone answered it, but then i went searching and found the one i was looking for! Any chance it's [*Los Pintín Al Rescate*](https://los-pintin.fandom.com/wiki/Los_Pint%C3%ADn_Al_Rescate_(2000))?

> The Pintíns are relaxing at “the beach” with the other penguins, at the edge of the South Pole. A sinister human ship materializes from the fog and kidnaps Luna, who is alone on a float offshore. The rest of the family go to her rescue. They find that Luna and a captured boy penguin, Guibor, have been taken to millionaire mad scientist Jorba Tarjat’s private volcanic island zoo, where he mutates his animals into grotesque combinations. They have to rescue her (and Guibor, though they don’t know about him yet) from Tarjat (also voiced by Argentine actor Arturo Maly) and his comic-relief henchmen Cacho (the fat one) and Tacho (the thin one) before she can be turned into anything, or the volcano erupts. Some of the other animals are more helpful than others, including Tuco, a flying monkey (one of Jorba Tarjat’s experiments, crossed with a bat); Chubers, a vain horse who used to play the cowboy hero’s steed in movies; and the elephant and mouse lovers.

It's in a couple languages, but no English, which is why its's so hard to find.

Comment: OMG YES IT IS THANK U SO MUCH